# Why belongToMany is not working in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to define a Many to Many relationships using "belongsToMany" relationship between 2 tables with a lookup table.

These are my tables:

I have a `category_product` like this

[image: demo]

ProductController.php

```
public function index()
{
    $categories = Category::with('products')->where('parent_id', 0)->get();
    return view('Home.lists.product', compact('categories'));
}
```

Category..php

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
}
```

product.blade.php

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
    @foreach($category->products as $product)
        @dd($product->id)
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

I see this. `3 // resources\views/Home/lists/portfolio.blade.php`

I want to return `3`,`5`,`4`.

It is returned only `3.` and I want to return all products.

Comment: If that `dd()` is not being triggered, it might be due to `$category->products` being empty. In your Controller do `dd(Category::has('products')->where('parent_id', 0)->exists());`; if that is `false`, you have you answer.

Comment: I see this message `true // app\Http\Controllers\PortfolioController.php:12`

Comment: Ok, so that means you have at least 1 `Category` model that has `Products`, and it's `parent_id` is `0`. Did you try something like `@foreach($category->products as $product)`, then `{{ $product->id }}`? I haven't seen or used this `@dd()` directive before.

Comment: I changed the data https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZv1o.png but I see this. `3 // resources\views/Home/lists/portfolio.blade.php`

Comment: Then it's working  `{{ $product->id }}` would return `3`, `5` and `4` in that `@foreach(...)` loop. Is something still wrong?

Comment: No, It is something still not wrong now.

Comment: I want to return `3`,`5`,`4` .

Comment: It is returned only `3`. and I want to return all products.

Comment: You are, aren't you? Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75452099/edit) with your new code and output; it's not clear what you changed or what is now happening.

Comment: Did you remove `@dd($product->id)` and use `{{ $product->id }}` like I suggested? `dd()` means **dump and die**, and no more code will be executed once you hit this...

Comment: Yes, I changed `{{ $product->id }}`, It return to `3 4 5 `

Comment: Yeah, so only use `dd()` for testing purposes and understand that when you call `dd()`, it will execute once, then die. In a `foreach()` loop, it will only show 3, since that was the value on the first loop, then it dies. Any other issues?

Comment: Yess, I want to create like this demo. https://www.bootdey.com/snippets/view/portfolio-with-category-filter-using-isotope-js

Comment: That's not an issue with the code you posted though... Please attempt to make that layout yourself, and if you get stuck in a certain spot, _then_ it's appropriate to ask a question on Stackoverflow. Please remember that SO is technical Q and A site, not a site to get help with implementing designs, etc.